# Encrypting data for webserver

Tags: web-server

I'd like to send sensor values over ethernet shield to a webserver. But for this I'd like to encrypt the data on the arduino and decrypt it on the webserver (PHP).
Do you have any suggestions or examples?

Answer (score 1):

XTEA is probably your best bet.  It's lightweight, easy to implement, and secure enough for a bit of sensor data...

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA

There's also the slightly more complex, and also slightly more secure, XXTEA:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA